# Calling "require" inside a function

Tags: php, function, scope, global-variables, require

In the page I'm working on, the first thing I do is include my `tools.php` file. Say, `index.php`

```
require("../scripts/tools.php");
```

Next, I create a custom css

```
$custom_css = [
    $link([
        "rel"   => "stylesheet",
        "type"  => "text/css",
        "media" => "screen",
        "href"  => BASE . "css/layout-list.css",
        ]),
];
```

and include the head element using a custom require function which is declared inside the `tools.php`.

```
req("template/head.php");
```

The reason I'm using a custom `require` is because I need to increase the `../`s on each path everytime I go deeper in the folder structure. I don't want to add them manually.

There is a `base()` function in the `tools.php` and it automatically calculates the `../`s necessary to reach back to the main folder, and assigns it to a `BASE` constant. This `BASE` constant is used in the `req()` function

```
function req($path) {
    require(BASE . $path);
}
```

This (kind of) works. The problem is, since (the actual) require was called inside a function, `head.php` can't access `$custom_css`, and `index.php` can't access any variable inside `head.php`.

---

The solution I've came up with is to declare that the variable is global before using it.

So, if I have to access `$custom_css` that's in `index.php` from `head.php`, in `head.php` I do:

```
global $custom_css;
if (!isset($custom_css)) {
    $custom_css = [];
}
```

and if I have to access a variable that's in `head.php` from `index.php`, I must declare the variable globally inside the `head.php`:

```
global $head_var;
$head_var = 4;
```

This process seems very tiring and redundant. Isn't there a way to change where the `require` effects? Make all the variables in the included file global even though the file was included in a function?

Comment: Can't you do something like `require(req('someting_here'));`? Just return what needs to be required, don't `require()` it inside the function.

Comment: @FirstOne I assume you've read BeetleJuice's answer, and my comment. If there's no general solution, I'll probable use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your custom `req` does is prepend a constant defined in `tools.php`, why not use the constant directly?

```
require(BASE."template/head.php");
```

Comment: Initially, that's what I did. But I'm curious if there's a more general solution. Since I've created a template, I do a lot `requre`. Using `req("file.php")` instead of `require(BASE."file.php")` seems much cleaner, but troubling.